# Index out of range in number of rows in section during fetching data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

When to try open new controller with my tableview and progress bar I have "Index out of range".
I fetch data from Firestore Database and the idea is that when I tap button "next" I want to update progress bar and reload table view with new values. Number of rows must be equal number of sets, but each exercise has different amount of sets, so I want to change number of rows dynamically.

```
class StartViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

  var titleValue: String = ""
  var dayOfWorkout: String = ""
  var exerciseNumber = 0

  var models: [DataCell2] = []
  let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
  var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
  @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
  @IBOutlet weak var exerciseLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var progressView: UIProgressView!


  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()
       
     progressView.transform = progressView.transform.scaledBy(x: 1, y: 3)   
     tableView.delegate = self
     tableView.dataSource = self
     retrieveWorkouts()
  }
    
  @IBAction func nextButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
     nextExercise()
        
     Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.2, target: self, selector: #selector(updateUI), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
     tableView.reloadData()
  }
    
  @objc func updateUI() {
     progressView.progress = getProgress() 
  }
    
  func getProgress() -> Float {
     return Float(exerciseNumber) / Float(models.count)
  }
    
  func nextExercise() {
        
     if exerciseNumber + 1 < models.count {
        exerciseNumber += 1
     } else {
        exerciseNumber = 0
     }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
      **//HERE IS ERROR**  
      return models[exerciseNumber].sets!
  }
```

And methods to fetch data from firestore

```
func retrieveWorkouts() {

   db.collection("users").document("\(user!.uid)").collection("WorkoutsName").document("\(titleValue)").collection("Exercises").order(by: "Number").getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
      if let error = error{
         print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
      }else {
         if let snapshotDocuments = querySnapshot?.documents {
            for doc in snapshotDocuments {
                let data = doc.data()
                if let numberDb = data["Number"] as? Int, let exerciseDb = data["Exercise"] as? String, let kgDb = data["kg"] as? Int, let setsDb = data["Sets"] as? Int, let repsDb = data["Reps"] as? Int, let workoutName = data["workoutName"] as? String {
                    print("data is \(data)")
                    let newModel = DataCell2(Number: numberDb, Exercise: exerciseDb, kg: kgDb, sets: setsDb, reps: repsDb, workoutName: workoutName)
                    self.models.append(newModel)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }                   
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Try calling `reloadData` on the main thread inside `retrieveWorkouts` method. And are you sure about the logic inside `nextExercise`? I think you switched the if and else conditions inside of it.

Comment: Unfortunately reloadData inside main thread doesn't work

Comment: You should nonetheless do that. And are you sure about the `nextExercise` method?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. The only things that doesn't work is retrieving number of sets to number of rows in section function.

Comment: This is a little off topic but you're not going to want to reload your tableView over and over inside the for loop `for doc in snapshotDocuments`. Move the reload after that so it only has to do it once after the dataSource is populated.

Comment: You're also force unwrapping an optional `models[exerciseNumber].sets!` which may be causing an issue as well. Best bet it to protect your code with guard, if let or nil coalescing operators like `return models[exerciseNumber].sets ?? 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a timing issue.  The view will try to create the tableView when it loads.   At that point the models array will be empty as the async firebase method won't have run and updated it.  But you initialise exerciseNumber to 0.

This means that the `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method will try to access `models[0`] but as the array is empty at this point this doesn't exist and causes the index out of range crash.

You can fix this by a bit of defensive programming:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
      guard !model.isEmpty else {return 0}
      return models[exerciseNumber].sets!
  }
```

You could also add a second guard or a precondition to ensure that exerciseNumber < models.count. While from the bit of code you have posted this should not be necessary, it's never a bad idea to programme defensively.

Answer (score 1):

You are basing the number of rows on
`models[exerciseNumber].sets!`

and you are setting the exercise number in

```
func nextExercise() {
        
     if exerciseNumber + 1 < models.count {
        exerciseNumber += 1
     } else {
        exerciseNumber = 0
     }
  }
```

However you have a logic error in here:  you are checking the exercise number is less than the models.count, and if so increasing it.  This will lead to exerciseNumber == models.count, and as arrays are zero-indexed this will be beyond the end of the array and give the out-of-range error.

An easy fix would be to change the method to:

```
func nextExercise() {
   exerciseNumber += 1
   if exerciseNumber == models.count {
      exerciseNumber = 0
   }
   return exerciseNumber
}
```

There are smarter ways of doing this, but this will work for now.

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work. But I have a doubt if my logic in nextExercise is bad, because I start from exerciseNumber = 0, if exerciseNumber is greater than models.count I increment, but when exerciseNumber will be equal to models.count my exerciseNumber will be again 0, so I will start from the beginning, what's wrong here?

Comment: I apologise - I misread that as `if exercise < model.count`.  I managed to miss the `+ 1` bit both while reading and then cut and pasting.  My bad!